# Stubbing ES6 class fields with sinon (solving "Cannot stub non-existent property" / "Property does not exist!")

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, es6-class, stub

I have a class:

```js
class Foo {
  baz = 3;

  bar() {
    return 5;
  }
}
```

I am able to stub `bar()` both on an instance and on the class itself:

```js
  describe("#bar", function() {
    it("can be stubbed on an instance to return 25", function() {
      const foo = new Foo();
      sinon.stub(foo, "bar").returns(25);
      expect(foo.bar()).to.equal(25);
    })

    it("can be stubbed on the class to return 30", function () {
      sinon.stub(Foo.prototype, "bar").returns(30);
      const foo = new Foo();
      expect(foo.bar()).to.equal(30);
    })
  })
```

However, when I try with a field:

```js
  describe("property baz", function() { 
    it("can be stubbed on an instance to equal 9", function() {
      const foo = new Foo();
      sinon.stub(foo, "baz").value(9);
      expect(foo.baz).to.equal(9);
    })

    it("can be stubbed on the class to equal 12", function() {
      sinon.stub(Foo.prototype, "baz").value(12);
      const foo = new Foo();
      expect(foo.baz).to.equal(12);
    })
  })
```

The second test fails with:

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent property baz
```

I've found questions on here about stubbing properties of objects, but I've not seen anyone address this specific issue.

Ideally, I'd use `createSubInstance` and just fill in my own fake fields and methods, but that gives me a variant of the same problem:

```js
    it("can be faked on a stub instance", function() {
      const foo = sinon.createStubInstance(Foo, {
        baz: 12,
      });
      expect(foo.baz).to.equal(12);
    })
```

This errors with:

```
Error: Cannot stub baz. Property does not exist!
```

Answer (score 0):

`baz` is a [Public instance fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)

> Public instance fields exist on every created instance of a class

`baz` does not exist on `Foo.prototype` and you are trying to stub it. that's why you got the error:

> TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property baz